# iot media player noise

Tags: uwp, media-player, iot

I'm working on a UWP on raspberri pi 3 with VS 2015, I have a problem with mediaPlayer object. it works correctly but it has a noise in begin and end of each file, I need to play some small MP3 (or any other codec) files one by one, between each files I hear two noises that annoy me. any body has a solution. I checked the files in my PC there is no noise in them, these noise just happen in UWP. the code is as below :

```
async Task PlayVoice()
    {
        MediaPlayer player = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
        player.AutoPlay = true;
        player.RemoveAllEffects();
        player.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_Loop;
        player.Volume = 1;
        player.SetUriSource(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Sound/" + f[vc] + ".mp3"));
          vc++;
    }

    void MediaPlayer_Loop(MediaPlayer player, object e)
    {
        if (player == null)
            return;
        if (vc >= f.Length)
            return;
        player.SetUriSource(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Sound/" + f[vc] + ".mp3"));
        vc++;          
    }
```

Comment: When you say these noise just happen in UWP, did you actually mean the noise only happens in IoT devices?

Comment: I didn't check it in other IOT devices but it only happening in RPI. On my Desktop it never happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an audio stops and before the following one starts, there is a gap between them and it is a source of annoyance to listeners. You can try to use MediaPlaybackList because [items in a MediaPlaybackList are rendered using gapless playback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx). The code like this:

```
void PlayBackList()
{
    MediaPlaybackList mediaPlaybackList;
    MediaSource mediaSource;
    MediaPlaybackItem mediaPlaybackItem;

    MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();

    mediaPlaybackList = new MediaPlaybackList();

    for (vc = 0; vc < f.Count; vc++)
    {
        mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Sound/" + f[vc] + ".wma"));
        mediaPlaybackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(mediaSource);
        mediaPlaybackList.Items.Add(mediaPlaybackItem);
    }

    mediaPlaybackList.AutoRepeatEnabled = true;
    mediaElement.SetPlaybackSource(mediaPlaybackList);
    mediaElement.AutoPlay = true;
    mediaElement.Play();

}
```

In addition, the problem manifests itself as a loud pop or click, just before sound is output and just after sound output is stopped. This is because a PWM output of the BCM2835 CPU is being used, rather than a standard DAC. When the PWM function is activated, there’s a jump in output voltage which results in the popping sound. A more detailed explanation is [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/128#issuecomment-14556086).

Comment: Thank you Rita for your answer, But I faced a new problem, It almost solved the pop sound but after changing the code to Playlist as you wrote above, some files not playing, I think small files not playing. playing starts well, but when it reaches to a small file it does not play more.

Comment: "Small"?How much? In my test, smallest file is 96KB.